# Finding $g'(2)$ given $f(x)$ and $f(g(x))$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Let $f(x) = e^x + x + 1$ and $f(g(x)) = x$. Find the value of $g'(2)$

Here is my attempt:

Because $f(g(x)) = x$, that means I need to find what value of x will make $g(x)$ satisfy $f(x) = x$.

Using inverse differentiation I can find this:
$$f^{-1}(x) = e^y + y + 1$$

which means:
$$g(x) = e^x + x + 1$$

so the derivative of g(x) is:
$$g'(x) = e^x + 1$$

which means:
$$g'(2) = e^2 + 1$$

Which step did I go wrong?

Comment: $f^{-1}(x) \ne e^y + y + 1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that $f(g(x)) = x$ means $g(x) = f^{-1}(x)$. (We can skip $g(f(x)) = x$ because $f(x)$ is a"nice" function.) Then, $g'(x) = \frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}$, so $g'(2) = \frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(2)}$. To find $f^{-1}(2)$, note that $f(0) = 2$ and $f(x)$ is one to one, so $f^{-1}(2) = 0$. Thus:

$$g'(2) = \frac{1}{f'(0)} = \frac{1}{e^{0} + 1} = \boxed{\frac{1}{2}}$$

Comment: Thanks. So I should have just kept $f^-1$ as a function?

Comment: Yeah, basically. It's usually not worth it to actually find $f^{-1}$ in terms of $x$.

Comment: Is it even possible to find $f^-1(2)$ algebraically? Or are questions like these designed by giving you a value which you can find by plugging in 0 to the original function?

Comment: $f^{-1}(\text{value})$ is almost always a nice integer / small fraction which you can find after a bit of plugging things in. And no, it's not possible to find $f^{-1}$ algebraically in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Since $\;g=f^{-1}\;$ (why? Why is $\;f\;$ even invertible?) then by the theorem of the derivative of the inverse funcion

$$g'(x)=\frac1{f'(f^{-1}(2))}$$
so...